# How to bind to viewmodel property in DataTemplate WP7

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm unable to bind to viewmodel property in DataTemplate. I want to show/hide globally checkboxes in ListBox.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template">

<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Background="Gray" cal:Message.Attach="[Action Check( $dataContext )]" />
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have, and what's not working. This question is currently way too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem before. I've created ViewModelLocator class, which has public properties to my view models. These properties are retrieved through IoC container:

```
public partial class ViewModelLocator
{
    public MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel
    {
        get { return this.containerLocator.Container.Resolve<MainPageViewModel>(); }
    }
}
```

Then you need create static resource in your App.xaml:

```
    <Application.Resources>  

         <viewmodels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>

    </Application.Resources>
```

And finnaly you can use this in DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template">
   <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding MainPageViewModel.IsVisible, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: We can set name on User Control or Page Control (it holds ViewModel Data Context) and use it similar to example that you provided above.

Comment: I tried this but my object does not have the `containerLocator` property, is there some missing code which defines this?